# Spring SAML - Using multiple IDP certificates from keystore instead of metadata XML

Tags: single-sign-on, metadata, x509certificate, keystore, spring-saml

- I was able to integrate my application (SP) with Okta (IDP).

  - I will be only performing IDP-initiated logins.
  - But Okta will not be my only IDP and I do not want to keep adding new IDP metadata XML's to my applications (because that means I need to edit my spring XML file and add a new IDP and restart the server).

**So I just want to import the IDP x509certificates (public key) into my keystore and use them to verify my SAML responses. Is that possible?
Or in other words, I want to register an IDP at runtime without making any changes to my application or restarting it.**

If yes, can you provide resources on how to do that?

Currently I have provided Okta's metadata XML like below in my application's spring xml file.

```
<bean id="metadata" class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.MetadataManager">
    <constructor-arg>
        <list>
        <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.FilesystemMetadataProvider">
            <constructor-arg>
                <value type="java.io.File">C:\\DEV\\idp_metadata\\metadata.xml</value>
            </constructor-arg>
                <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool" />
        </bean>
        </list>
    </constructor-arg>

</bean>
```

Thanks,

Abhishek

Answer (score 0):

I completed the changes to my application to make it dependent on an IDP's certificate present in a keystore.
But with a caveat, if a new IDP certificate is added in future, it requires a server restart.

1. I changed the `securityProfile` to `pkix` instead of the default `metaIOP`

   `<bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadataDelegate">
      <constructor-arg>
         <bean class="org.opensaml.saml2.metadata.provider.ResourceBackedMetadataProvider">
            <constructor-arg>
               <bean class="java.util.Timer" />
            </constructor-arg>
            <constructor-arg>
               <bean class="org.opensaml.util.resource.FilesystemResource">
                  <constructor-arg value="${path.to.SP.metadata}" />
               </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
            <property name="parserPool" ref="parserPool" />
         </bean>
      </constructor-arg>
      <constructor-arg>
         <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.metadata.ExtendedMetadata">
            <property name="local" value="true" />
            <property name="securityProfile" value="pkix" />
            <property name="sslSecurityProfile" value="pkix" />
            <property name="requireArtifactResolveSigned" value="false" />
            <property name="requireLogoutRequestSigned" value="false" />
            <property name="requireLogoutResponseSigned" value="false" />
            <property name="idpDiscoveryEnabled" value="false" />
            <property name="supportUnsolicitedResponse" value="true" />
         </bean>
      </constructor-arg>
   </bean>`
2. Added the certificate to a .jks file: `keytool -importcert -file certificate.txt -keystore keystore.jks -alias "Alias"`
3. Implemented a `SAMLContextProviderLB` and injected `pkixresolver`

   `<bean id="contextProvider" class="org.springframework.security.saml.context.SAMLContextProviderLB">
      <property name="scheme" value="${saml.loadBalancer.scheme}" />
      <property name="serverName" value="${saml.loadBalancer.serverName}" />
      <property name="serverPort" value="${saml.loadBalancer.serverPort}" />
      <property name="includeServerPortInRequestURL" value="${saml.loadBalancer.includeServerPortInRequestURL}" />
      <property name="contextPath" value="/contextPath" />
      <property name="pkixResolver">
         <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.trust.PKIXInformationResolver">
            <constructor-arg index="0" ref="metadataCredResolver" />
            <constructor-arg index="1" ref="metadata" />
            <constructor-arg index="2" ref="trustedKeyManager" />
         </bean>
      </property>
      <property name="storageFactory">
         <bean class="org.springframework.security.saml.storage.EmptyStorageFactory" />
      </property>
   </bean>`

   `<bean id="metadataCredResolver" class="org.springframework.security.saml.trust.MetadataCredentialResolver">
      <constructor-arg index="0" ref="metadata" />
      <constructor-arg index="1" ref="trustedKeyManager" />
      <property name="useXmlMetadata" value="false" />
   </bean>`

   `<bean id="trustedKeyManager" class="org.springframework.security.saml.key.JKSKeyManager">
      <constructor-arg value="${saml.trust.jks.filePath}" />
      <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="${saml.trust.jks.password}" />
      <constructor-arg>
         <map>
            <entry key="${saml.trust.jks.defaultKey.name}" value="${saml.trust.jks.defaultKey.password}" />
         </map>
      </constructor-arg>
      <constructor-arg type="java.lang.String" value="${saml.trust.jks.defaultKey.name}" />
   </bean>`
4. Implemented a few classes to override the need of a metadata XML.
   `SAMLProcessorImpl` and `WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl`

I remove the dependency on `getPeerEntityID` / `getPeerEntityMetadata.getEntityID()` and replace it with `response.getIssuer().getValue()` because both have to be the same for SAML to work.
The trust certificates are obtained from the keystore which is loaded once during startup.

**In my next update I will try to figure out how to perform a timed refresh of the .jks file to load new certificates.**

Comment: Can you explain #4 - Implemented a few classes to override the need of a metadata XML. SAMLProcessorImpl and WebSSOProfileConsumerImpl in a bit more detail?